# adobe premiere cc / picture in picture / editing video shape by its corners removed?

Tags: premiere

I remember old times when I could just put a video on a layer and drag each corner individually to shape it as I want but it seems in premiere cc this easy to use feature is removed or replaced with some effects for achieve the same effect by entering many many values.
or there is some option in some menu that I can't find to re enable it. (please tell me this is the case)
can a pro enlighten me in this matter please?

Answer (score 3):

Double click the layer in the program monitor (the sequence viewer) or click on the little icon in the source view next to the **Motion** effect to bring up the drag handles.

[image]

Comment: that handles I already have but they won't move individually and I can't drag one cornet without moving any other corner.

Comment: Yup, the way it works now is that the footage scales around its anchor point (the circle in the middle) So you'll have to scale then move, or change the anchor point then scale. AFAICT there is no tool that does both at once like AE has.